# Pointers on C, need simple verification

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

Question is part of Reek's earlier mentioned handbook.
I got variables:

```
h under 1080 address with value 1020
i under 1020 address with value 1080.
```

Evaluate `L-value` and `R-value` of an expression **h, when treating `h` and `i` as `pointers` to `integers`.
My answer is `R:1020 L:1080`, but Instructor's guide says: `R:1080, L:1020`.
Who right and who's wrong?

```
Step by step:
R-value first:
h=1020
*h=*(1020)=1080
**h=*(*h)=*(1080)=1020
L-value:
same, but value is address of value 1020, so 1080.
```

Ok, here is the code that should work.If it works as planned it proves that **h in this case = h.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int * h;
  unsigned int *i;
  unsigned int ans=0;

  h=&i;
  i=&h;
  printf("h=%u &h=%u i=%u &i=%u\n", h, &h, i, &i);

  ans=*(unsigned int *)*h;
  printf("**h=%u\n", ans);

  *(unsigned int *)*h=1;

  printf("h=%u &h=%u i=%u &i=%u\n", h, &h, i, &i);

  return 0;

}
```

And here' output I get:

```
h=3214580856 &h=3214580852 i=3214580852 &i=3214580856
**h=3214580856
h=1 &h=3214580852 i=3214580852 &i=3214580856
```

In last line I did **h=1;

Comment: Statistically seen the Instructor is right.

Comment: Please show your work. What led you to your answer, step by step? That will help sort it out.

Comment: Why downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Have you ever heard term, "Lies, damned lies, and statistics?"

Comment: I did not downvote you, don't know the reason, but suspect it may be due to your vagueness.  In any case, maybe [this link will help](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3750.html)

Comment: Question is very precise, am I right about the way I solve it, or not...And if not-where's my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
addr | value
...  | ...
1020 | 1080    <-- i
...  | ...
1080 | 1020    <-- h
```

and code would look the following way:

```
int* h;
int* i;
h = &i; // h pointing to the address of i (= 1020)
i = &h; // i pointing to the address of h (= 1080)
```

so `**h` is equal to `*i`, Now the real question here is: What does it mean to "evaluate R-value of the expression" `*i`? ...What's the difference between l-value and r-value in this case?

[MSDN's article on "L-Value and R-Value Expressions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx) states: *"An identifier is a modifiable  l-value if it refers to a memory location... if `ptr` is a pointer to a storage region, then `*ptr` is a modifiable l-value that designates the storage region to which `ptr` points."* ~ in other words: if you look at the expression `*i` as l-value, it is just the same as using `h` directly. ~> value of `h` == 1020.

It also states: *"The term "r-value" is sometimes used to describe the value of an expression and to distinguish it from an l-value. All l-values are r-values but not all r-values are l-values."* ~ in other words (my interpretation for this case): if you look at `*i` as r-value, you should not look at it as an alias for the variable `h` but rather the value of an expression itself. ~> explaining why `*i` could be considered `&h`.

Comment: but isn't value of h used as L-value 1080? *i=*&h=h. **h=h?

Comment: @zubergu: The confusion lies in interpretation of "Evaluate R-value of expression `*ptr`". Check my edit, maybe it will make more sense now.

Comment: I think it means what value will produce **h= and =**h;

Comment: @zubergu: Using an expression at the left side of the assignment doesn't make it l-value.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a moot point, because if "all the variables are pointers to integers" as I instructed, the expression **h is illegal. Double indirection would only be legal on a pointer to a pointer to an integer. This is my mistake. Earlier C compilers were less picky about strong typing of variables and would have generated code for this expression. However, experience taught the C world that this was not a good idea, so strong typing became the norm. But now suppose we change the expression

**h     to   **(int **)h

The R-value of h is 1020 (the value stored there). The R-value of *h is the value stored at 1020, namely 1080. Then the value of **h would be the value stored at 1080, namely 1020. The L-value would be the address of this final result, namely 1080. So you are correct and I screwed up. Good catch.